# Bio::DB::Fasta, Can't call method "index_file" on an undefined value at script.pl line

Tags: perl, bioperl

I would like to reload a pre-index file in perl which has been previously indexed as following:

```
./first_script.pl hg19.fa

use Bio::DB::Fasta;

my $db = Bio::DB::Fasta->new($file_fasta);

...
```

in an another script I would like to re-load the existing indexed file.

./script.pl hg19.fa.index input

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Bio::DB::Fasta;

my $fasta_index_file = $ARGV[0];
my $input_file = $ARGV[1];

open(FH,"<$input_file");

my $db->index_file($fasta_index_file);
```

in the description it syas

```
 Title   : index_file
Usage   : $db->index_file($filename)
Function: (re)loads a sequence file and indexes sequences offsets in the file
Returns : seq offsets in the file
Args    : filename,
           boolean to force reloading a file
```

but it returns the following error:

```
Can't call method "index_file" on an undefined value at script.pl line
```

in the second script if I use again:

```
my $db = Bio::DB::Fasta->new($file_fasta);
```

it immediately goes to the next step! Does it mean that it already realized it exists?

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining `$db` anywhere in your second script.

As is often the case, `use strict;` would have revealed this, and should be your first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: my $db = $db ->index_file($fasta_index_file);  ??

Comment: Quick examination of the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/BioPerl/Bio/DB/Fasta.pm) suggests using `tie` to connect to an existing database.